# How to make Customer Billing Phone Number Unique in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

Actually I want customers to add unique-phone numbers in the billing address of woo-commerce. if any tries to add / update already existed phone numbers then it should throw an error.

I tried the below code but it is not working. Can anyone give me the correct solution for unique phone numbers in the Woocommerce billing address?

```
add_filter( 'update_user_meta', 'ts_unique_wc_phone_field');
function ts_unique_wc_phone_field( $errors ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        $hasPhoneNumber= get_users('meta_value='.$_POST['billing_phone']);
            if ( !empty($hasPhoneNumber)) {
        $errors->add( 'billing_phone_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Mobile number is already used!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
  }
    return $errors;
}
```

[image: Customer Billing Form]

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_users` call is wrong. Use

```
$hasPhoneNumber = get_users(array(
        'meta_key' => 'billing_phone', 
        'meta_value' => $_POST['billing_phone'], 
    )
);
```

**Careful**: you did not mention your meta **key** in your post. This might be something else than 'billing_phone'. Adapt it as necessary.

This will however allow users to do shenanigans like adding a space/-/+ or something like that to the phone number, reusing it. This might need a function to filter out redundant characters upon meta value insertion, and apply the same function to `$_POST['billing_phone']` before the meta query for get_users.

Comment: No, it's not working.


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function add() on string in....

Answer (score 0):

I have setup on one of my sites the same code within two (2) functions - one for woocommerce -> my account, and one at the checkout which checks for validity of the phone number provided specific to my country, and the other to check if the phone number already exists.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 'wc_myaccount_validate_billing_phone', 20, 1); // My Account
function wc_myaccount_validate_billing_phone( $args ){

    if ( isset ( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && !empty ( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) { 

        if ( !preg_match( '/^04[0-9]{8}$/D', str_replace( ' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) ) {

            wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Billing Mobile Phone</strong> is invalid (Example: 0412 345 678).' ), 'error' );
        }

        $existing_billing_phone = get_users( 'meta_value=' . str_replace( ' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( !empty ( $existing_billing_phone ) ) {

            if ( $current_user->billing_phone != str_replace( ' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
                wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Billing Mobile Phone</strong> already exists.' ), 'error' );
            }
            else { 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_checkout_validate_billing_phone'); // Checkout
function wc_checkout_validate_billing_phone() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && !empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) { 

        if ( !preg_match('/^04[0-9]{8}$/D', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Billing Mobile Phone</strong> is invalid (Example: 0412 345 678).' ), 'error' );
        }

        $existing_billing_phone = get_users( 'meta_value=' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( !empty( $existing_billing_phone ) ) {

            if ( $current_user->billing_phone != str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
                wc_add_notice( __( '<strong>Billing Mobile Phone</strong> already exists.' ), 'error' );
            }
            else { 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I want to save all phone numbers as 0412345678 (no spaces) and some people enter phone numbers as 0412 345 678, the str_replace() removes this prior to saving.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'wc_checkout_save_billing_phone' );
function wc_checkout_save_billing_phone( $user_id ) {   

    if ( $user_id && $_POST['billing_phone'] ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_phone', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );
    }
}
```

While I have not tested this next part yet, and this example is referenced from [this link](https://carlofontanos.com/adding-extra-user-profile-fields-in-wordpress-admin/), if you are wanting to update the admin user area you may want to use something like this.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'wc_checkout_validate_billing_phone', 10 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'wc_checkout_validate_billing_phone', 10 );
```

Below is a screenshot of the results of trying to change my phone number to one that already exists while in the woocommerce->my account section.

[image]

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function add_action(), 1 passed in                  (second function). And the first function is also not working it is simply updating already existing phone numbers.

Comment: I use a class and had to make changes to the add_action before providing. Please find the following changes made to the answer: `add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_checkout_validate_billing_phone');` (I forgot to put the appropriate --> ' <--  surrounding the functions).

Comment: Updated my answer with admin user area if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, it is not working. either it is not showing any error also.  Already existing phone numbers are updating in the admin area and checkout form also.

Comment: Hopefully someone can add to this then as it works in mine. Sorry @Nagendra.

Comment: No, Problem @Aliqua bro. I made the phone number field read-only. I disabled for edit.

Comment: Added an screenshot to the answer just for anyone else that may be searching for this answer.